# pulp interdependent constraints

Tags: python, pulp

Trying to solve the following problem using PuLP package, but don't know how to add interdependent constraints between Adwords and SEO channels.

> Maximize total revenue. We are to allocate funds to 4 marketing campaigns: a TV ad, SEO,Adwords and Facebook. ROI on each campaign is: 9% on TV 14% on SEO 10% on Adwords 5% on Facebook. The total budget is $1,000,000. 
>   Search Engine Marketing (SEO + Adwords) is the primary focus and spend must
>   exceed 60% of the total budget. Social media campaign on Facebook
>   should cost no more than 20% of the budget. Production and airing of a
>   TV ad will cost a minimum of $200,000. Minimal contract with a social
>   agency for Facebook advertising is $80,000. An SEO content creation
>   agency needs between  60,000and60,000and 220,000. The marketing
>   strategy says that Adwords cost should be no more 3 times the SEO
>   costs. Channels have varying reach. It has been estimated using the
>   number of customers you can reach by spending $1 in each channel: TV –
>   2.5 customers-per-dollar SEO – 2.1 customers-per-dollar Adwords – 0.9 customers-per-dollar Facebook – 3.0 customers-per-dollar The number of
>   customers in the market base is estimated to be around 1.3 million
>   people. You should allocate spend to match that number with campaign
>   reach.

When I add the non-numeric constraint, it replaces my objective function. How can I add interdependent constraints in PuLP?

Answer (score 1):

```
adwords = LpVariable("adwords", 0, 1000)
SEO = LpVariable("SEO", 0, 1000)

prob = LpProblem("problem", LpMaximize)

prob += adwords <= 3*SEO
```

This shouldn't replace your objective function as it contains the '<='.  Fill in the rest as usual.